# kubuntu can't change file associations

Tags: kubuntu, file-association

For some mysterious reason, since recently png files are opened with gimp and not with gwenview. When I try to change that in `System Settings / Applications / File Associations`, the changes are not persistent. That is, I change the order, click apply, close System Settings, reopen it, and it's back to the previous configuration. I have also tried to find the actual configuration file, but neither `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` nor `~/.config/mimeapps.list` exist on my computer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you see with `find . ! -user $USER -ls`? The command may take a little while to complete.

Comment: In which directory shall I execute this search?

Comment: From your home folder.

Comment: Then it prints just every file in my home folder and its sub folders (at least it seems that way, it prints thousands of lines). Edit: I have a mounted sub-folder `~/extern/`, at least it prints a lot of files from that folder.

Comment: Okay, so at some point in the past, you've used `sudo` in such a way that all the files (and folders) you see in the output are owned by `root` and not by you. You'll need to fix that.

Comment: Thanks, that was the trick.

Comment: You're most welcome! Feel free to post an answer as this may help others.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was given by DK Bose in the comments. Some of my config files were owned by root, not by me. In my case, I could find these files by

```
find .  -path "./extern/*" -prune -o ! -user $USER -ls
```

where the first part of the command excludes my external drive `./extern` from the search.

After changing the owner and group of `~/.config/mimeapps.list` (and all other files in `~/.config`) I could successfully change the file associations in the system settings.